# How can I relate an RKHS norm to the sup norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume $\mathcal{H}$ is an RKHS and $f\in \mathcal{H}$ is a function such that $\left\|f\right\|_{\mathcal{H}} \leq C$.

Is there any way I can bound $\left|f(X)\right|$? Is this just $\left|f(X)\right|\leq C$ as well?

If it helps, I'm using an RKHS with the radial basis kernel but I'd be interested to know if it generalizes anyway.

Comment: My thought was that $f(x) = <f(t),K(x,t)> \leq \left\| f\right\|_H \sqrt{k(x,x)}$ and $k(x,x)=1$ if $k(x,y)=e^{-\sigma^2 \left\|x-y\right\|_2^2}$. Just want to confirm this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is correct, you can just use Cauchy-Schwartz
$\newcommand{\H}{\mathcal{H}}$
$$f(x) = \langle f, k(\cdot, x) \rangle_\H \le \lVert f \rVert_\H \lVert k(\cdot, x) \rVert_\H = \sqrt{k(x, x)} \lVert f \rVert_\H$$